# Прийом ліків чи приймання ліків?

Tags: вживання-слів, віддієслівні-іменники

Завжди чув вираз: "прийом ліків", "після прийому ліків" і т.п. І тут [LanguageTool](https://languagetool.org) (перевірка граматики та вживання слів) показує, що правильно "приймання".

То як все-таки правильно?

Comment: Ось слушна думка: *приймає ліки завскладу, а пацієнт їх може вживати або заживати, можна ще ковтати або пити, а приймати – це про склад.* [Звідси](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27824#p27820)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Словники радянських часів

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах (1970–1980):

> **[ПРИЙО́М](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjom)**, у, *ч.*
>
> 1. Те саме, що **приймання** 1—6, 8, 11—13. <…>
>
> <…>
>
> ---
>
> **[ПРИЙМА́ННЯ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjmannja)**, я, *с.* Дія за значенням **приймати**.
>
> > <…>
> > *Насамперед необхідно встановити певні години приймання їжі і точно додержувати їх* (Українські страви, 1957, 28);
> > <…>
>
> ---
>
> **[ПРИЙМА́ТИ](http://sum.in.ua/s/pryjmaty)**, аю, аєш, *недок.*, **ПРИЙНЯ́ТИ**, *рідко* **ПРИНЯ́ТИ** і *діал.* **ПРИЙМИ́ТИ**, прийму́, при́ймеш, *док.*, *перех.*
>
> <…>
>
> 6. <…>
>
> // Вживати всередину, ковтати (ліки).
>
> > *Я вигадав, що заслаб.. Підняв тривогу, мусив приймати краплі од живота і зіпсував великодній сніданок* (Михайло Коцюбинський, II, 1955, 364);
> > *Олечка не хотіла нічого приймати, дивилася з докором своїми синіми очима, пручалася. Утрьох тримали її, з великим трудом вкинули в рот дві таблетки* (Антон Хижняк, Тамара, 1959, 189);
> > *Доктор Драгомирецький вирішив прийняти подвійну дозу вероналу, — щоб таки переспати часинку* (Юрій Смолич, Мир.., 1958, 61);
>
> // <…>
>
> <…>

Тобто і «приймання», і «прийом» мають потрібне значення (дія за значенням приймати 6).

## R2U і LanguageTool

«Словник української мови» в 11 томах є одною з найґрунтовніших спроб систематизації української лексики. Але (як і безліч праць радянських часів) він викликає в багатьох людей нарікання щодо перекручення тенденцій української мови з метою наближення її до російської. Мені важко судити, так це чи ні, але дехто ставиться до слів, що з'являються лише у «Словнику української мови» в 11 томах / лише в радянські часи з недовірою, намагаючись опиратися на авторитет старіших (дорадянських) словників.

Іноді такі погляди розділяють і розробники R2U та LanguageTool, намагаючись відчистити українську мову від невдалих кальок радянських часів і відмічаючи такі в тексті як орфографічні чи то стилістичні помилки.

#### Критика позиції R2U і LanguageTool щодо слова «прийом»

Погляди R2U і LanguageTool у конкретно даному випадку не видаються мені обґрунтованими тому, що вони (станом на квітень 2017) будь-який вжиток «прийом» вважають неправильним (а не лише в контексті ліків):

> прийом — помилкове слово, виправлення: приймання, прийняття, вітання, зустріч, напад, захід, раз, спосіб, удаль, вдача.

Але ж можна знайти вжитки слова прийом до 1910-х років (хоч і не щодо ліків):

- «Словарь росийсько-український» Уманця і Спілки (1893–1898): [прийом](http://r2u.org.ua/s?w=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC&scope=ukr&dicts=9&highlight=on).
- «Словарь української мови» Бориса Грінченка (1909): [прийом](http://hrinchenko.com/slovar/znachenie-slova/47573-pryjom.html#show_point).
- Тарас Шевченко, Григорій Квітка-Основ'яненко, інші.

Можна знайти й сучасні вжитки слова прийом в авторитетних джерелах (хоч і не щодо ліків):

- «Словники України on-line» (2006) від Українського мовно-інформаційного фонду НАН України теж вважають слово «[прийом](http://lcorp.ulif.org.ua/ElWelding/Home/ContactUs?lang=uk&ww=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC)» коректним.
- Новий «Словник української мови» в 20 томах (2010–…) ще не містить літери «П», але [вживає слово «прийом» 6 разів](//www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BE%D0%BC+site:services.ulif.org.ua/expl/&filter=0) в інших статтях.
- Журнал «Культура слова» Інституту української мови майже в кожному випуску містить слово «прийом»: [81](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/kultura-slova-81.pdf), [82](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/kultura-slova-82.pdf), [84](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/kultura-slova-84.pdf).

## Висновки

Я не знаю, на що спиралися розробники R2U і LanguageTool в своїх рішеннях щодо слова «прийом». Можливо, вони мають рацію про якісь конкретні випадки.

Але ж вони стверджують, що «прийом» помилкове взагалі. Це не знаходить підтвердження.

Мабуть, Вам залишається спиратися на власне чуття мови, принаймні доки не вийдуть томи на літеру «П» сучасного тлумачного «Словника української мови» в 20 томах. Але мені особисто спроба заборонити «прийом» видається гіперпуризмом. (Не треба забувати про інші, точніші синоніми — але й «прийом» є.)

## Доповнення

#### Доповнення 1. *Вживати* чи *приймати* ліки?

Вже на початку XX століття ліки було можна і *вживати*, і *приймати*:

- > Часом лиш журив ся, коли почало / болїти єго в серединї, / і пильно він лїків домашних вживав / та спав у спокійній „яскинї“.
  > *<sub>//«Новик», зі збірки [«Поезиї Осипа Маковея» (1895, Львів)](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Makovei_Osyp/Poezyi_Osypa_Makoveia/), [ст. 92](//books.google.com/books?id=4pxDAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D1%96%D0%B2+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B8%D1%85+%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B2%22).</sub>*
- > Дем'ян перемінив свою думку про непотрібність ліків, і я знаю, що навіть хворим говорив він, що ліки приймати треба, бо святі лікарі давали їх. Але в потребу дезінфекціи та чистоти він все таки не вірив і колись навіть сказав мені, що такого й святі лікарі певне не веліли робить.
  > *<sub>//[Модест Левицький, оповідання (1907), ст. 141](//books.google.com/books?id=kQ5DAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22%D0%BB%D1%96%D0%BA%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%22).</sub>*
- > Я тепер маю приймати нові лїки... А коли я вживаю що нове, то почуваю себе погано... і тепер так буде: я передбачаю.
  > *<sub>//Михайло Жук «Погасле світло», з журналу [«Літературно-науковий вістник» Наукового товариства імені Тараса Шевченка, річник XVI, книжка V (1913)](http://elib.nplu.org/view.html?id=7985), [ст. 225](//books.google.com/books?id=zxBJAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96+%D0%BB%D1%97%D0%BA%D0%B8%22).</sub>*
- > Нарештї, я чую, він виймає з шкафи шклянку і рішучим тоном радить, як приймати лїки.
  > *<sub>//[Михайло Івченко «Шуми весняні»](http://bukva.mobi/mihaylo-ivchenko-shumi-vesnyani.html), з журналу «Літературно-науковий вістник» Наукового товариства імені Тараса Шевченка, річник XIX, книжка XII (1918), [ст. 74](//books.google.com/books?id=JRNJAQAAMAAJ&dq=%22%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8+%D0%BB%D1%97%D0%BA%D0%B8%22).</sub>*

Позиція, що [*приймає* ліки завідувач складу (на склад), а пацієнти їх *вживають*](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27824#p27820), нічим не підкріплена. Наявність однієї (здавалось би, логічнішої) конструкції не виключає можливості існування інших (з іншою логікою творення та з іншим походженням).

<sub>Я не знаю, звідки взялось «приймають» щодо ліків у російській і українській мовах. Але, здається, застосування «нетипових» дієслів до ліків — явище міжнародне. Поляки *biorą* («беруть») ліки (*leki*), англійці *take* («беруть») медикаменти (*medicine*) тощо. Можливо, це (прямі чи опосередковані) кальки з одного джерела.</sub>

#### Доповнення 2. Про статтю «Чим можна замінити прийом?» Катерини Городоцької

Є (згадана у [відповіді Andriy](//ukrainian.stackexchange.com/a/1264/4)) стаття Катерини Городоцької «Чим можна замінити прийом?» з [78-го випуску журналу «Культура слова»](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/kultura-slova-78.pdf), де автор пропонує, чим можна замінити слово «прийом» у різних випадках, в тому числі «прийом ліків» на «вживання ліків». Підтримуючи Катерину Городоцьку загалом щодо надмірності вживання слова «прийом», неоптимальності його в багатьох випадках і значно кращому звучанні виразів «приймальне відділення», «приймальня» (за «прийомне відділення», «прийомна»), все-таки зазначу, що:

- Здається (див. цитати вище), ліки можна і *вживати*, і *приймати* — тому можливість застосування іменника «вживання» (від «вживати») для позначення цього процесу сама собою не закриває питання вибору (чи відсутності) іменника, утвореного від дієслова «приймати».
- Враховуючи, що в тому ж (78-му) випуску журналу «Культура слова» слово «прийом» використовується 11 разів у 7 інших статтях 8 інших авторів (не кажучи вже про інші випуски) — це не виглядає повною забороною використання слова «прийом». Очевидно, що саме слово «прийом» в українській мові таки є — хоча це саме собою не доводить, що йому слід надавати перевагу чи що воно доречне саме до ліків (а не в значенні, наприклад, «літературний прийом»).

Comment: "Я не знаю, на що спиралися розробники R2U і LanguageTool в своїх рішеннях щодо слова «прийом». Можливо, вони мають рацію про якісь конкретні випадки. Але ж вони стверджують, що «прийом» помилкове взагалі. Це не знаходить підтвердження". — Усе дуже просто: в українській мові немає словотвірної моделі, коли б з "приймати/прийняти" утворювалося "прийом".

Answer (score 9):

З обговорення цієї теми на форумі r2u, [«Прийом»](http://r2u.org.ua/forum/viewtopic.php?p=27824):

Укр. слова приймання/прийняття, спосіб, захід, раз виконують ту функцію, що її в рос. мові має *приём*. Академічний російсько-український словник у 4-х тт. (2011-2014рр.), що його важко назвати гіперпуристичним, до рос. *приём* подає *прийом* лише один раз та й то у сполуці (а не відповідником до значення) й на другому місці після спосіб (див. нижче).
В сучасній мові потреби в слові *прийом* немає, а в словниках r2u воно зафіксоване лише у вузькому й тепер застарілому контексті *"прийом рекрутів"* та в сполуці *Богу в прийом*.

[Стаття Катерини Городенської](http://www1.nas.gov.ua/institutes/ium/new_books/Documents/kultura-slova-78.pdf): (Національна академія наук України Інститут української мови)

> Донедавна зі значенням дієслова *приймати* в українській
>   мові широко вживали іменник *прийом*, про що свідчить багато
>   узвичаєних словосполук із різних професійних сфер, пор.: *прийом студентів*, *прийом відвідувачів*, *прийом їжі*, *прийом ліків*,
>   *години прийому*, *дні прийому*, *пункт прийому*, *бути на прийомі
>   в лікаря*, *записатися на прийом до лікаря*, *ліки на два прийоми*,
>   *влаштувати прийом* (з нагоди кого-, чого-небудь).
>
> Цілком очевидно, що названі словосполуки є **буквальним перекладом відповідних російських** зі словом *прием*, тому що **в українському
>   іменниковому словотворенні немає зразка**, за яким би міг утворитися іменник *прийом*. Його потрібно замінити органічними
>   для української мови словами *приймання*, *вживання*, *споживання* та ін. (пор.: *приймання відвідувачів*, *приймання студентів*, *споживання їжі*, *уживання ліків*, *години приймання*) або
>   прикметником *приймальний* (пор.: *приймальні дні*, *приймальні
>   години*, *приймальний пункт*, *приймальний покій*).

Стаття *приём* у РУС, т.3, 2013, с. 471:

> 1. (действие) приймання, прийняття (с.); п. в партию приймання
>      (прийняття) до партії (в партію); п. гостей приймання (прийняття)
>      гостей; п. пищи приймання (прийняття) їжі;
> 2. (отдельный момент
>      процесса работы, деятельности) захід, -ходу; в один п. прочесть книгу
>      за одним разом (заходом; присест: присідом) прочитати книжку, одним
>      заходом (відразу) прочитати книжку; переписать статью за два ~ма
>      переписати статтю за два заходи (разг. напади, двома нападами);
> 3. (в
>      остальных значениях) прийняття; (способ — ещё) спосіб, -собу; быть на
>      ~ме у кого бути на прийнятті в кого; лекарство на два ~ма ліки на два
>      рази; литературный п. літературний засіб (прийом); оказать блестящий
>      п. влаштувати урочисту зустріч; оказать хороший п. кому добре (гарно)
>      прийняти (привітати, ушанувати) кого, добре поставитися до кого,
>      виявити добре ставлення до кого; п. у врача приймання (прийняття) в
>      лікаря; разные ~мы лечёния різні способи лікування; часы ~ма
>      приймальні години.